# best way to insert data in mysql table from list interaction

Tags: python, mysql

I have a big json file (+- 50mb) which i have to iterate over, process some text, and then insert the processed text to a mysql table.

My doubt is:

Would it be better to insert record by record in the table while iterating over the json file.

```
move one item in json -> extract info I need -> open db connection -> insert record -> close db connection -> move to next item in json file... and so on until end of file
```

In this case would it be better to open and close db connection every time or leave it open until the end of the json file?

Or the other option I thought would be to iterate over the json file and create a list of dictionaries (one dictionary for each record, with keys as the field where to insert and the value of the key as the value to be inserted in the database) and then insert at the database.

```
iterate over json file -> extract info I need -> store info in dictionary -> add dictionary to a list -> repeat until the end of the file -> open db connection -> iterate over list -> insert record
```

In this case would it be possible to insert the whole list in the database at once instead of iterating over the list with a for...i... to insert record by record?

Any ideas on what would be the best option?

Sorry if the question might look stupid but I am a beginner and could not find this answer anywhere... I have over 100.000 records to insert...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely much better to insert all records into the database in one go: there is considerable overhead in creating and closing connections, and executing multiple INSERT statements instead of just one. Perhaps 100.000 records is a bit much to insert at once, if mysql chokes try adding chunks of e.g. 1000 records in one go.

I am assuming memory usage will not be an issue; this depends of course on how large each record is.

My advice would be to use [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) to access the database, if you often need to access databases from python. Definitely worth the investment! With sqlalchemy, the code would be something like this:

```
CHUNKSIZE = 1000

< parse JSON >
< store into a list of dictionaries 'records' >

< Refer to sqlalchemy tutorial for how to create Base and Session classes >

class MyRecord(Base):
  ''' SQLAlchemy record definition. 
      Let the column names correspond to the keys in the record dictionaries
  '''
  ...

session = Session()
for chunk in [records[CHUNKSIZE*i:CHUNKSIZE*(i+1)] for i in range(1+len(records)/CHUNKSIZE):
  for rec in chunk:
    session.add(MyRecord(**rec))
  session.commit()
```